# Cannot get custom notification to work Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to get a custom notification to work and although I have no issues with android 4.0 and upwards, I cannot get it to work correctly in 2.3.3 (API v10). Below is the result that I have:
[image: Incorrectly displaying notification]

As you can see the text is not visible, neither is the progress bar.

Below is the XML used for the RemoteView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ongoing_notif_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ongoing_notif_image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/notif_contentDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textAppearance = "@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent" />/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/ongoing_notif_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ongoing_notif_image"
        android:textAppearance = "@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/ongoing_notif_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ongoing_notif_image"
        android:layout_below="@id/ongoing_notif_title" 
        android:textAppearance = "@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/ongoing_notif_pgStatus"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ongoing_notif_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ongoing_notif_image"
        android:textAppearance = "@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent" /> />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have added the 'android:textApprearance' after following this suggestion [stackoverflow item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4935191/1627113)

Still no success though. Please note that this works fine on Android 4.0 upwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending many hours searching for it, I found the solution in another stackoverflow question and I though that I will post it here in case someone else comes across this question. The answer [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574534/1627113) and is caused by a bug in the support library as shown [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30495).